# Count over relative dates in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables on `Amazon Redshift` and they look as follows:

```
Tablename: Groups

GroupID    Created
1          2016-08-04
2          2017-05-24
3          2017-06-12

Tablename: GroupActivities

GroupID    CreationTime    ActivityType
1           2016-08-13        Assign
1           2016-09-13        Assign
2           2017-05-25        Create
2           2017-05-27        Assign
3           2017-06-24        Create
3           2017-06-28        Assign
```

I would like to count the number of activities within each 30 day period from group creation. For example, I would like the output to be the following:

```
GroupID    Period    ActivityCount
1          Period1    1
1          Period2    1
2          Period1    2
3          Period1    2
```

I could do this if the dates were not relative, but I'm not sure how to achieve this when the dates are relative. Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join the tables by group id, use integer division of date difference to identify the period and aggregate:

```
select
 group_id
,'Period'||((a.creationtime::date-g.created::date)/30+1)::varchar as period
,count(1) as activity_count
from groups g
join activities a
on g.groupid=a.groupid
group by 1,2
```